# What's the recommended workflow to use scripts, models, animations etc. that bought from Unity asset store?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Say I bought different items in the Unity assets store, including scripts, models, animations, etc. After importing, they are all in different folders under the 'Assets' or 'Assets/Plugins' with their brand name, and each of them has its own folder structure.

Should I put what I need to my own folders or just leave them where they were originally?

Things to consider: I will make some changes of the scripts, animations, prefabs of models. And the assets I bought probably will upgrade, and I want things that I used to upgrade with it. So what is the recommended workflow to use them?  Any experiences are welcomed, thank you!

Comment: "best" is subjective, as some would argue that best is not to use someone elses generically done thing but your own, others would say only import specifically that which you need, it should be most should work from anywhere in the asset folder list, and you can move them, but a lesser one might be hard coded...

Comment: Thank you. I changed "best" to "recommended".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I think it's a great question, and have often wondered about this myself, i.e.: Will my moving of items or renaming of folders -- useful for organization -- be problematic for future upgrades? ArtS, if I recall correctly the assets will still find their way in an upgrade even if you moved them, but I would love to hear from an expert on this, too, as I'm not entirely sure about Unity's process here.

Comment: Thank you @Philipp Lenssen. I worry that after I make some changes, and the future upgrades will overwrite my changes. There's no official guide on this. Every newbies like me are just blindly trying things out. It'll be very helpful if any veterans could share their experience. :)

Answer (score 2):

Moving the plugin to a different folder won't affect future plugin upgrades, However, getting into the plugin and altering the source code or content will end up conflicting with the future version. I recommend not altering the plugins original content.

In case if you do want to override then, either you can have a wrapper script around the plugins script and customize it based on the necessity, or use version control(like `git`) while upgrading plugins in a separate branch and later merge your edited version of the plugin vs the latest version of the actual plugin.

Also unity these days has a well organized `packages` directory system, which you can refer to custom organize the external third party plugins.

Comment: PS: When upgrading a modified plugin without version control, Unity will replace your changes in the script or in the media file with the latest one from the plugin. So you will end up losing your changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience. One more thing, every thing I bought in asset store and import via package manager are going under "assets" instead of  "packages". Is it not supposed to be like this?

Comment: Currently, Things bought from the asset store will go into the `assets` directory whereas packages imported from the package manager will go into the `packages` directory. Can you tell me what package from the package manager is getting into the `assets` folder?

Comment: For example "PuppetMaster", "Warrior Pack Bundle 2 FREE", "Fighter Pack Bundle FREE", a free 3D model called "Knight", "Unity-Chan! Model", pretty much everything are under "assets". And I import all of them using package manager.

Comment: The ones you mentioned here are all from unity's `asset store`, hence they will always be loaded into the `assets` folder. When I said `packages` what I meant was Unity's new [package management system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.package-manager-ui@1.8/manual/index.html), which includes packages like `Entities`, `Text-mesh-pro` etc, only packages from the package manager will end up in the `packages` folder, not the ones from the asseStore.

Comment: Oh, that explained. I always confused these two types, since I imported them all by the package manager. Thank you for finally solving this myth for me :)